# If $ f(x) = \left\{\frac{3x}{2}\right\}\;,$ Where $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x \rfloor$. Then real solution of $f(f(x))=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions, function-and-relation-composition

> If $\displaystyle f(x) = \left\{\frac{3x}{2}\right\}\;,$ Where $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x \rfloor$. Then no. of solution of the equation
>
> $f(f(x))=0$  and $f(f(f(x)))=0$ and $f(f(f(f(x))))=0$.

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ We can write  $\displaystyle f(x)= \left\{\frac{3x}{2}\right\}=\frac{3x}{2}-\lfloor \frac{3x}{2} \rfloor  = \left\{\begin{matrix}
\displaystyle \frac{3x}{2} \;,& 0\leq x<\displaystyle \frac{2}{3} \\\\ 
\displaystyle \frac{3x}{2}-1 \;,& \displaystyle \frac{2}{3}\leq x<\displaystyle 1 
 & 
\end{matrix}\right.$

Now for Solution of $f(f(x)) = 0.$ We have used Two cases.

$\bullet$ If $0\leq x<\displaystyle \frac{2}{3} .$ Then we use $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{3x}{2}.$ So $\displaystyle f(f(x)) = 0\Rightarrow \frac{9x}{4}=0\Rightarrow x=0$..

$\bullet$ If $\displaystyle \frac{2}{3}\leq x<\displaystyle 1  .$ Then we use $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{3x}{2}-1.$ So $\displaystyle f(f(x)) = 0\Rightarrow \frac{9x}{4}-\frac{5}{2}=0\Rightarrow x=\frac{10}{9}$.

So we get only one solution $x=0$ for $f(f(x))=0$

Is my solution is Right, If not , Then plz explain me how can i solve it.

Comment: If any of the answeres below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $f(f((\frac23)^2))=0$, so $0$ is not the only solution.

> $\bullet$ If $0\leq x<\displaystyle \frac{2}{3} .$ Then we use $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{3x}{2}.$ So $\displaystyle f(f(x)) = 0\Rightarrow \frac{9x}{4}=0\Rightarrow x=0$..

The mistake you are making is that even when $0\le x\le \frac23$, $f(x)$ may not be in the same interval. Such is the case with $(\frac23)^2$, it is strictly between $0$ and $\frac23$, but $f((\frac23)^2)$ is $\frac23$, which is not.

Can you see why this does not yield every solution?

---

Here is how I found all the solutions to $f(f(x))=0$.

$f(f(x))=0$ if and only if $\frac32f(x)$ is an integer. This is the case if and only if $f(x)$ is some integer multiple of $\frac23$. $f$ can only return values in $[0,1)$, however, so $f(x)$ must be either $0$ or $\frac23$.

$f(x)=0$ if and only if $\frac32x$ is an integer:

$$\frac32x=n\implies x=\frac23n$$

And so, $x=\frac23n$ is a solution to $f(f(x))=0$ for every integer $n$.

$f(x)=\frac23$ if and only if $\frac32x$ is $n+\frac23$ for some integer $n$:

$$\frac32x=n+\frac23\implies x=\frac23n+\left(\frac23\right)^2$$

And so, $x=\frac23n+\left(\frac23\right)^2$ is a solution to $f(f(x))=0$ for every integer $n.$

In conclusion, the solutions to $f(f(x))=0$ are all numbers of the forms  $\frac23n+\left(\frac23\right)^2$ and $\frac23n$ for integer $n$.

Comment: Let me know if you don't understand or need clarification on something in my answer.